# In python 3 how can I return a variable to a function properly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently in school studying python and have a question. I am working on a midterm project that has to take an input, assign it to a list, if the first letter isnt capital - capitalize it..and count the number of words in the sentence.

While my code works.. I can't help but think I handled the arguments into the functions completely wrong. If you could take a look at it and help me out on how I could clean it up that would be excellent.
Please remember - I am new..so explain it like I am 5!

````
    sentence_list = sentList()
    sentence = listToString(sentence_list)
    sentence = is_cap(sentence)
    sentence = fix(sentence)
    sentence = count_words(sentence)

def sentList():
    sentence_list = []
    sentence_list.append(input('Please enter a sentence: '))
    return sentence_list

def listToString(sentence_list):
    sentence = ""
    sentence = ''.join(sentence_list)
    return sentence

def is_cap(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.capitalize()
    return sentence

def fix(sentence):
    sentence = sentence + "." if (not sentence.endswith('.')) and (not sentence.endswith('!')) and \
     (not sentence.endswith('?')) else sentence
    return sentence


def count_words(sentence):
    count = len(sentence.split())
    print('The number of words in the string are: '+ str(count))
    print(sentence)



main()```
````

Comment: I know you've said this is a homework assignment, so nonsensical requirements may not be your fault. But is there any reason to be putting your single-string sentence into a one-element list only to turn it back into a single string immediately afterwards? Could the `sentList` be expected to contain a loop that takes multiple entries?

Comment: you are correct that it is homework assignment... and it wanted the input stored in a list.The issue i was running into was modifying the list in the sense of appending a "." at the end of it, capitalizing the first word, and counting words.
Though now that I think about it - I can probably do that just with append on the list right? again, fairly knew so i was just doing what made sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, your code is very good as a beginner, good job dude.
so
to make your function run, you need call it after you defined them. but here you put the call at the top of the page.
the reason of that is python read the codes from top to bottom, so when he read the first that call a function that he didn't read 'til this line
the code should be like this:

```
def sentList():
    sentence_list = []
    sentence_list.append(input('Please enter a sentence: '))
    return sentence_list

def listToString(sentence_list):
    sentence = ""
sentence = ''.join(sentence_list)
return sentence

def is_cap(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.capitalize()
    return sentence

def fix(sentence):
    sentence = sentence + "." if (not sentence.endswith('.')) and (not sentence.endswith('!')) and \ (not sentence.endswith('?')) else sentence
    return sentence


def count_words(sentence):
    count = len(sentence.split())
    print('The number of words in the string are: '+ str(count))
    print(sentence)

sentence_list = sentList()
sentence = listToString(sentence_list)
sentence = is_cap(sentence)
sentence = fix(sentence)
sentence = count_words(sentence)
```

I guess that it. if you have any another question. this community will always be here

Comment: Thank you very much. I purchased on udemy the coding bootcamp and have a LITTLE BIT of experience with javascript and other things.. that while completely different - I feel are similar and more importantly exposed me to stack overflow and things like that. So my resources are there if I am unsure on something :)
I appreciate your guidance! I wasn't sure mainly if continually calling "sentence = ...." was the proper way to handle it. I'll adjust mine accordingly :D

Comment: glad to hear that. keep going 'cause you do perfect <br> also if my answer could help you, so please confirm my answer<br> have a nice day